# CSS doesn't block rendering on Firefox Quantum

Tags: css, firefox, browser, rendering, firefox-quantum

With Firefox Quantum I noticed a "glitch" on loading the CSS of some websites.

**One of these is [my company's website](https://www.doveconviene.it/discount):**

[image: DoveConviene Website]

**Or Github too:**

[image: Github Website]

In the first one, we have only one CSS file in the `<head>` section of our pages.

It seems that - only in Firefox Quantum - the CSS doesn't block the render of the page [as it should](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css). The rest of the page loads without the CSS for some instants, then the CSS is applied as if it loads asynchronously (but it's not).

Obviously, this behavior doesn't happen in all the websites I visited.

I really have no clue what's going on :)

Comment: that used to happen a lot back in the day, actually i didn't know CSS resources became blocking, thought it was the web speed that solved that.. is the waiting time you experienced really long?

Comment: Hi @Kaddath I thought that putting CSS in the <head> section of document would block rendering. The waiting time is the same as the gifs that I uploaded...

Comment: I don't know enough about the blocking process as i said. Anyway, placing `<style>` tags in the `<head>` is a strong guarantee that the styles are applied with no delay (html code parsing is sequential), but i can't confirm for linked files. However, from my console, the main CSS files in `<head>` are already loaded before 250ms, the visual changes you see after may come from something else. By the way, loading time for images is separated from the CSS loading itself, so images are a whole different topic.

Comment: I'm noticing this too for a website I'm creating with Craft CMF using Firefox 59.0.2 and it is very annoying. It doesn't happen under Chrome.

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468

Answer (score 3):

To summarize information from [bug 1404468](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468), the "flash of unstyled content" ("FOUC") usually happens when something asks for information depending on styles before the stylesheets are loaded:

- Scripts on the page that [force layout/style recalc](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), that are executed before the stylesheets are loaded.

  - It's [recommended](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468#c16) to "Put all your styles in  and make sure that any script that asks for layout information comes after them".
  - Be careful with `defer` scripts, which [may execute before the stylesheets are loaded](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468#c58) ([spec bug](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3890)).
- [An `iframe` that loads faster than parent page's stylesheets](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687441) forces layout of the parent page for complicated reasons, described in the bug.
- Addons ([example](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1437644)) which ask for layout information before the styles finished loading (i.e. on [`run_at: "document_end"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at)). Firefox 60 (2018-05-09) [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1437921) FOUC with the addons that queried layout using `run_at: "document_idle"`, and a few add-ons were fixed around the same time.
- Firefox had a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712130) causing it on sites with `autofocus`, notably GitHub. Also fixed in Firefox 60.

Factors that do not cause FOUC by itself, but can increase the chances of it being visible:

- Firefox 53 [reduced](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283302#c0) `nglayout.initialpaint.delay` (which delays the initial painting of a page after it stopped being blocked by stylesheets, assuming the HTML is not fully loaded by that time) from 250ms to 5ms.

  - If the FOUC-causing stylesheets happen to load before the delay, you won't see the unstyled content. With 5ms it became much less likely.
  - If the HTML page itself loads slowly, you may see some content jumping around the page with more likelihood.
- Slow network combined with the factors above increases the chances of seeing the FOUC.

Finally, it's common to see the fonts on the web page "upgrade" to page-provided web fonts, because they don't block the initial rendering by design.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix that worked for me (from vrancken.gilbert in [bug 1404468](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468)):

```
<body>
<script>0</script>
<!-- Your code ... -->
</body>
```

> (...) if you add a dummy script right after your  tag FF will only render the page when the CSS is loaded.

### Additionnal info :

If you manage the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) in your application (prevents inline-script), it's necessary to white-list this line :

**For example :**

In your application :

```
<script nonce="JwkbSbZ2MYNwp5Adp8Nk">0</script>
```

In your 'Content-Security-Policy' HTTP Header :

```
(...) script-src 'self' 'nonce-JwkbSbZ2MYNwp5Adp8Nk'
```

Ref : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)